# View in adapter and dialog

Tags: android, view, dialog, adapter

In my application I have an `Adapter` that extends `BaseAdapter`. Inside that class there is method

```java
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View view = convertView;
    if (view == null) {
      view = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.childitem, parent, false);
    }

    Product p = getProduct(position);

    ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvDescr)).setText(p.name);
    ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvPrice)).setText(p.price + "");
    ((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivImage)).setImageResource(p.image);

    CheckBox cbBuy = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.cbBox);

    cbBuy.setOnCheckedChangeListener(myCheckChangList);

    cbBuy.setTag(position);

    cbBuy.setChecked(p.box);
    return view;
}
```

In the `MainActivity` of my application I am trying to use custom `AlertDialog` with two `EditText`s for input. It did not work properly and have got recommendation to use `View` for accessing my resources.

```java
void newItemInput(){

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();

    final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_signin, null);

    builder.setView(v);

    builder.setTitle("");
    builder.setMessage("");

    builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {


            EditText item_name = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
            EditText item_price =(EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.item_price);

            String text = item_name.getText().toString();
            String text_price = item_price.getText().toString();
            int price = Integer.parseInt(text_price);

            // Do something with value!
            products.add(new Product(text, price, R.drawable.unread, false));

            item_name.setText("");
            item_price.setText("");

        }
    });
```

Now when I insert data in `Dialog` to use it as argument at the following statement:
    products.add(new Product(text, price, R.drawable.unread, false));
... it behaves in a strange way. Does it happen because of contradictions between `View` call in adapter and dialog? If so, what could be done to solve it?

Comment: Is 'products' a list of products or the adapter?

Also, when you say strange way, what exactly does happen?

Comment: ArrayList<Product> products = new ArrayList<Product>();  Strange means I put text and price from dialog to products as an argument to create new item in ListView and the first entry comes only when I do second one. For example text=a; price=0 (first invocation of dialog), text=b, price = 1 (second invokation). When second entered comes first that did not show up in the firts plase. Second stands invisible and waites for the third. I assume that first stood hidden until second one is not entered.

Comment: Is it possible to solve this. I am a new one in android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you make any change to the data your adapter is maintaining, you need to call your adapter's [notifyDataSetChanged](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29) method. This will notify the attached view that the data has been changed and it should refresh itself. The weird behaviour you noticed is because this is called during the process of adding a new item to the list, but not after an item has been added.

More information on using adapters can be found here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#AdapterViews

Comment: Thanks a lot. That was my mistake and I already have managed it.